# OpenGL is drawing the UV map instead of the mesh

Tags: c++, opengl

I am following a youtube tutorial series for OpenGL development. He has uploaded the [code](https://github.com/BennyQBD/ModernOpenGLTutorial) on github. However the downloaded code seems to draw the UV map instead of the mesh itself.

I tried to isolate the problem and I think the problem lies in mesh.cpp. I could be wrong.
Maybe the problem is in the glDrawElementsBaseVertex line since we are not specifying the pointer to the indices array.

```
void Mesh::Draw()
{
    glBindVertexArray(m_vertexArrayObject);

    glDrawElementsBaseVertex(GL_TRIANGLES, m_numIndices, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0, 0);

    glBindVertexArray(0);
}
```

I have tried swapping the position and texture coordinates but that doesnt seem to work.

```
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_vertexArrayBuffers[POSITION_VB]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(model.positions[0]) * model.positions.size(), &model.positions[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_vertexArrayBuffers[TEXCOORD_VB]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(model.texCoords[0]) * model.texCoords.size(), &model.texCoords[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
```

Since I am new to OpenGL I am not able to fix this issue. I have already asked the youtuber and I am yet to get a reply.

Comment: it's probably in the fragment shader

Comment: Nope, I changed the fragment shader to output solid white. Doesnt solve the issue. I also messed with the vertex shader and swapped the texcoord with the position. It also doesnt solve the issue.

Comment: How do you take your inputs in your vertex shader? Since you are binding positions to attrib 0 and uvs to attrib 1 you should do something like:
layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;
layout (location = 1) in vec2 uvs;
Do you have that in your shader?

Comment: The youtuber used OpenGL version 120. Looks like my graphics card had some compability issues with it. I switched it to 330 and everything started to work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My graphics card probably had some compatibility issues with OpenGL 120 so I changed it to 330 and a made a few changes and everything started to work fine. Here are the changes I made.

basicShader.vs

```
#version 330

layout(location = 0) in vec3 position;
layout(location = 1) in  vec2 texCoord;
layout(location = 2) in  vec3 normal;

out vec2 texCoord0;
out vec3 normal0;

uniform mat4 MVP;
uniform mat4 Normal;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = MVP * vec4(position, 1.0);
    texCoord0 = texCoord;
    normal0 = (Normal * vec4(normal, 0.0)).xyz;
}
```

basicShader.fs

```
#version 330

out vec4 color;

in vec2 texCoord0;
in vec3 normal0;

uniform sampler2D sampler;
uniform vec3 lightDirection;

void main()
{
    color = texture(sampler, texCoord0) * 
        clamp(dot(-lightDirection, normal0), 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

Comment: In a 3.30 GLSL shader you should not be using `varying`. Beginning with GLSL 1.30 a vertex shader output should be declared `out vec4 foobar` and the corresponding input in the fragment shader would be declared `in vec4 foobar`. `texture2D` is also deprecated beginning with GLSL 1.30 (now texture lookups are all done using overloads of `texture (...)`). Everything else looks appropriate for a shader re-written for GLSL 3.30.